# Does Spark Subscription of Firestore allow cloud function such as Counting the collection size? Currently function is uploaded but invoked

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to update simple cloud function in firestore that counts the records of collection on write. The function gets deployed successfully but doesn't get invoked. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kezq3.png)

Comment: Hey there & welcome to StackOverflow Amit! Your question is incomplete and has little chances to get answered as is. Please read the **[How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** article & edit your question adding more information. Let's start with some snippets that you've worked on regarding the matter! (if you need help with this, read up on how to create a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**)

Comment: Yes, the [`child-count` sample function](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/child-count) should also work on the free Spark plan. If this doesn't work for you, update your question to include the minimum code that reproduces the problem (based on the assumption that the code sample is correct). Note that the sample I linked is for the Realtime Database, not for Cloud Firestore. If you're basing yourself on another example, please provide a link to that too (but also an MCVE in your question itself).